# WCF Net.TCP: Most efficient way to broadcast messages to a lot of clients

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, networking, tcp

I have a **WCF** service hosted with **Net.TCP** binding to which a lot of clients **(> 100)** may connect and receive various broadcast messages. The same message is sent to all clients and the current way I'm currently doing it is to have dedicated thread which waits on a BlockingCollection for new messages and as soon as new message arrives it iterates over the list of client callback connections and calls a method which receives the message as an argument.

So my code currently looks like this:

```
var msg = ... get message from queue ...
foreach(var client in clients)
    client.SendMessage(message)
```

This design has following problems:

1. Clients can not receive new message until I'm finished sending a message to all clients
2. I would like to detect slow clients and possibly disconnect them
3. The message is being serialized as many times as I have clients (I could change it so that I serialize the message before sending it but I would need to change the signatore of SendMessage to SendMessage(byte[] content) and this is not something I would like to do)

Does anybody has experience with such problems? Any tips/tricks/hints?

Comment: Are you already wed to NetTCPBinding? If you choose something like BasicHTTPBinding or NetHTTPBinding, which behave like web servers (request, response, close connection) you're not locked into a persistent connection, allowing hundreds of concurrent connections at any one time. But that would mean having a daemon program on each client  machine, periodically hitting the host and checking the queue for any outbound announcements.

Comment: You are suggesting that each client periodically polls the service. IMHO it is lot less efficient then the service pushing data to the client as the data arrives. Also I need the clients to have the up-to-date data which means that polling interval would have to be very small and that would make everything consume more resources.

Comment: You're correct about the clients polling the host ... that's what it would take using an HTTP-like protocol from WCF. Do you have a program resident on each client machine, listening for these inbound announcements? I

Comment: The client application (Windows Forms application) connect via standard WCF Net.TCP binding to my service which is listening on some port. When they connect the service retrieves and stores the clients callback channel so that it can send data to the client.
Think of it as a chat server where you only see incoming messages/

Comment: It's your program, but seems to me you could add to your client app a timer loop that polls the host queue for messages, closes the connection and wait for the next cycle. I've done both NetTCPBinding and BasicHTTPBinding; these HTTP-centric protocols are lightning fast. I've gotten, literally, hundreds of concurrent connections running on single server running BasicHTTPBinding, each on its own thread, up- and down-loading big files. So while on paper it seems like a less elegant and efficient solution, my load testing shows tells a different tale. And it eliminates the connection pool problem

Comment: I could make similar change to my current design by appointing a thread for each client to send a message to that client but I am pretty sure it can be more efficient then that. In any case the question is about efficiency with Net.TCP binding so maybe someone has an idea for Net.TCP. Thanks for the sugestion though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to use multicasts instead of dedicated communication. So each new client will need to join the cast channel (see IGMP for details) and then your server will fire-and-forget once per message you need to publish.

Comment: You are suggesting I switch to another technology? My question is - is it possible to be efficient with WCF? Perhaps WCF can not provide what I'm looking for but I would like to see if anybody has ideas how to make it work efficiently with WCF.

Comment: Creating Multicasting Applications using the UDP Transport: "WCF now supports writing multicasting applications using the UdpBinding. This transport is useful in scenarios where a service needs to send out small messages to a number of clients simultaneously." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556229(v=vs.110).aspx